# How to mark POSTing URLs?

Tags: html

Search engines and pre-fetching browser plugins can cause quite some trouble with `<a>` elements where the destination page changes the state of the server. In a `<form>`, I'd mark it as modifying with `method="POST"`. Is there a similar way to mark regular links as modifying?

`rel="nofollow"` does not solve the problem. From [the specification](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-nofollow):

> By adding rel="nofollow" to a hyperlink, a page indicates that the destination of that hyperlink should not be afforded any additional weight or ranking by user agents which perform link analysis upon web pages (e.g. search engines)

Comment: Semantically, you shouldn't use a link to change the state of a server. It's often best to have another page containing a form that your links can point to.

Comment: @lone: Is that from a UI perspective? If not, how could I emulate a text link using a form?

Comment: `input[type=submit] { background: none; border: none; color: blue; text-decoration: underline; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plain old link can only make get requests. A get request, as you indicated, should not trigger any destructive changes.

The solution, if you can't or don't want to have a form in your page at that point, is to have the link point to a page that does have a form. For instance, if you have a "delete" link it might point to a page that says "Are you sure you want to delete X? [delete]".

Then, if you don't want people to have to leave the page every time they delete something, you can implement some AJAX functionality in JavaScript.